# Не загружаются изображения из Firebase в RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, firebase

Я пытаюсь загрузить изображения из Firabase Storage, используя Bitmap. Но в приложении не отображаются фотографии.

Класс объекта:

```
package com.example.photo42_project;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;

import com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView;

public class _Marathon {
    Bitmap riv;
    String Name, month, day;
    int People, id;

   public Bitmap getRiv() {
       return riv;
   }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public int getPeople() {
        return People;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    public String getDay() {
        return day;
    }
}
```

XML-разметка объекта:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#A3F1FFE9"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp"
        app:strokeColor="#72E6DB"
        app:strokeWidth="1dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="5dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="5dp"></com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
        android:id="@+id/rv_photo"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:riv_corner_radius="10dp"></com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rv_tv_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/rv_photo"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/rv_photo"></TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rv_tv_people"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="19dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/rv_photo"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rv_tv_name"></TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/period"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/rv_tv_people"
            android:textSize="14dp"></TextView>



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Адаптер:

```
package com.example.photo42_project;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.DesignTool;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Adapter_Marathons extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter_Marathons.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;

    ArrayList<_Marathon> list;

    public Adapter_Marathons(Context context, ArrayList<_Marathon> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Adapter_Marathons.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_marathon, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Adapter_Marathons.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        int month, day, people;
        _Marathon marathon = list.get(position);
        holder.mrthn_name.setText(marathon.getName());
        people = marathon.getPeople();
        holder.ppl.setText("Участников: " + String.valueOf(people));
        holder.time.setText("Дата окончания: " + marathon.getMonth() + "." + marathon.getDay());

        holder.photo.setImageBitmap(marathon.getRiv());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        RoundedImageView photo;
        TextView mrthn_name;
        TextView ppl;
        TextView time;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            photo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv_photo);
            mrthn_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv_tv_name);
            ppl = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv_tv_people);
            time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.period);
        }
    }
}
```

Загрузка данных из Firebase

```
recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.marathonList);
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Marathons");
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        list = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter_marathons = new Adapter_Marathons(this, list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter_marathons);

        database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    _Marathon marathon = dataSnapshot.getValue(_Marathon.class);
                    int id = marathon.getId();
                    if (list.size() >= id + 1) {
                        if (marathon.getMonth() != list.get(id).getMonth()) {
                            list.get(id).month = marathon.getMonth();
                        }
                        if (marathon.getDay() != list.get(id).getDay()) {
                            list.get(id).day = marathon.getDay();
                        }
                        if (marathon.getPeople() != list.get(id).getPeople()) {
                            list.get(id).People = marathon.getPeople();
                        }
                        if (marathon.getName() != list.get(id).getName()) {
                            list.get(id).Name = marathon.getName();
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        list.add(marathon);
                        loadPhoto(id);
                    }
                }
                adapter_marathons.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            private void loadPhoto(int id) {
                FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
                StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("*тут мой url*").child("marathon_" + id + ".jpg");
                try {
                    final File localFile = File.createTempFile("images", "jpg");
                    storageRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(taskSnapshot -> {
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(localFile.getAbsolutePath());
                        list.get(id).riv = bitmap;
                    }).addOnFailureListener(exception -> {
                    });
                } catch (IOException ignored) {}
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Начните с того, что перестаньте писать вот так `catch (IOException ignored) {}`, и вот так `addOnFailureListener(exception -> {})`, а выведите ошибки в лог и прикрепите их в вопросу.

Comment: И вот тут тоже: `onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {}`

Comment: Возможно, дело в том, что загрузка картинок (которая не факт, что работает, т.к. вы игнорируете ошибки, как указали выше) происходит после того, как вы уведомили адаптер об изменениях. А после окончания загрузки картинок вы не уведомляете об этом адаптер. Проще, скорее всего, будет, по возможности, получать ссылки на картинки синхронно, а уже отображать их через к-л либу, например Glide, которая по ссылке картинки загрузит и отобразит.

Comment: И да, использовать Firebase стоит только если вы очень хороший специалист и знаете как её использовать и когда её не надо использовать. Для новичка Firebase - причина боли и отчаяния, разочарования в программировании вообще.

Comment: Во первых, после того как у тебя изменился ArrayList<_Marathon> lis в адаптере - вызывай notifyDataSetChanged() у recyclerView, может этого будет достаточно. А вообще, как писали выше,  лучше получай не битмапы,а ссылки для скачивания картинок с хранилища, как написано здесь - https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url. А в адаптере используя например Glide загружать их.